# Angular-UI-Router - change 3rd level nested view without knowing about 2nd level nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have few "parent modules", lets say

- user
- community

I also have "embedable modules", lets say

- photos
- videos
- wiki

My embedable modules can be embed to the parent modules.
All modules do not have cross dependencies. For example user does not know that he have photos, videos and wiki, but knows that he have list of embedable modules that will be embed to his page. And photos, videos and wiki are also do not know where they will be embed.

I have 3 layers of views:
- base view layer (top navigation bar, logo and so) - cares about parent view (does not know which one, is injected)
- parent object view layer (can be user, community or page, for example holds user photo and name) - cares about his embedable views (does not know that they are, are injected)
- embedable view layer - cares about what is inside his view

now lets say I am on the user page. User route is `#/user`. Now I want to access photos of the user via link, for example `<a href="#/user/photos/">user photos</a>`, but I cant do it because in the photos module the route name is `#/photos`, so `#/user/photos/` would not work.

If I access just `<a href="#/photos">user photos</a>`, it will remove parent view (**parent object view layer**, e.g. will remove user photo and name from the screen).

Any ideas how to access the photos module and persist parent view, and do not create hard coded dependencies by the way?

I need something like this:

```
$stateProvider
   .state(':parent/photos', {
            url: ':parent/photos',
            templateUrl: 'modules/photos/index.html',
            controller: 'PhotosCtrl'
       })
```

and use it from the user page like
`<a href="#/user/photos">user photos</a>`
or use it from the community page like
`<a href="#/community/photos">community photos</a>`

then photos module can use **:parent** param to determine its parent

OR at least I need linking functionality like:

`$stateProvider.state('user.photos', /*&*/'photos')`

to link modules on the global level.

Comment: Can you list all of the states you have in your stateProvider? Is there are 'user' state and 'community' state?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne, check this: https://gist.github.com/PLEEROCK/0d60243a6a0837cbb26f

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of a GalleryStateFactory is sound... But I would suggest you to add it as a provider instead... That would allow it to depend on the $stateProvide and you could do something like:

```
mod.provider('$galleryState', ['$stateProvider', function(sp) {

  this.galleryStates = function(parent) {
    sp.state(parent+'.gallery', GalleryStateFactory.default)
      .state(parent+'.gallery.photos', GalleryStateFactory.photos)
      .state(parent+'.gallery.albums',GalleryStateFactory.albums);
  }


  this.$get = angular.noop; //unless you wan't some service as well...
}]

$galleryStateProvider
    .galleryStates('user')
    .galleryStates('community');
```

Comment: nice! But my last implementation is to use my custom `StateHolder` service that register, manage and handle all states by himself. Override/prepending/appending states are available methods of the class

Comment: You should probably add an answer with your solution and then accept that so this Q can be closed ;)